# a = "stackoverflow" does not work in QBasic

Tags: type-mismatch, qbasic

The qbasic code returns a `type mismatch` error.

```
a="StackOverflow"
print left$(a,5)
print right$(a,8)
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I rectify it?

Comment: `$a = "string"`

Comment: Nope. `a$="StackOverflow"`. String variables have the suffix `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the way you have named the variable. 
"StackOverflow" is a string and cannot be assigned to variables of any other type.

In Qbasic, string variables must end with a `$` symbol. So try `a$` instead of `a`.

So try this code instead.

```
a$="StackOverflow"
print left$(a$,5)
print right$(a$,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variable as string first:

```
DIM a AS STRING
a = "StackOverflow"
PRINT LEFT$(a, 5)
PRINT RIGHT$(a, 8)
```